# VBA Pivot Table doesn't do anything

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My code for doing a Pivot Table doesn't actually do anything. It just creates a new sheet, but not the pivot table. 
In my workbook I will be having 2 sheets: one with the data and one with the pivot table.
This is my code:

```
Sub InsertPivotTable()
'Macro By ExcelChamps

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("DATA")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="Pivot_table")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Pivot_table")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot_table").PivotFields("data1")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
End With


ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot_table").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Pivot_table").PivotFields("data2"), "Count of data2", xlCount

'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot_table").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot_table").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't use `On Error Resume Next` without reverting back to `On Error GoTo 0`. If your code's throwing errors, you want to know what those errors are instead of trying to proceed regardless.

Comment: Besides the `On Error Resume Next`, I do not see any other code which might be creating a problem. You have the fields `Data1` and `Data2` right? Remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see if you are getting any error message

Comment: If I remove that, the error I get is "Subscript out of range"

Comment: You refer to both the `PivotTable` and `Pivot_Table` sheets. I doubt you have both...

Comment: PivotTable I wanted to be the new created sheet and Pivot_Table the name of the table. Shouldn't it be this way?